# How does google DeepDream work?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I  was looking into and reading about [Google deep dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepDream) (If you don't know what it is, I recommend you check it out!):

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me how it works.

I am still a high-school student, so I don't have a very in depth knowledge of programming, but all the descriptions of how it functions either get very technical (Wayyy over my head), or are very simple ("It makes things look more cat like").

I get the theory behind a neural net, but if anyone can explain how one actually is used to create those images, or at least point me in the direction of some reading you'd recommend, that would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this explanation is not too simple for your doing.

You give Google Deepdreams an image. It will start to look for every 'thing' it was trained to recognize. So the neural network might find a *dog*, *house* and *jellyfish* in an image.

But what Google Deepdreams does, is **amplify** these found objects. So when you run the recognization network again, instead of saying 'look, this is 40% certain a dog` it will result in 'look, this is 60% a dog'.

So every object it recognizes slightly, it will amplify, creating a new image. The resulting image contains amplified characteristics of all the objects the algorithm found.

> Even if you feed it white noise, it will amplify the slightest most minuscule resemblance to a dog into serious dog faces. *1

The algorithm is interesting because it actually shows what the algorithm is looking for to recognize certain objects.

*1 [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/3cbelv/eli5_can_anyone_explain_googles_deep_dream/)